# program for positive number at even index and and negative number at odd index

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Need Final Condition check for positive number if negative numbers are less than positive numbers in an Array

```
public class ArrayExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        int a[]= {12,3,-1,4,-2,8,-9,-6,4,78};
        int len=a.length;
        int i,j,k;
        int pcount=0,ncount=0;
        int b[]=new int[len];

        for(i=0;i<len;i++)   // for counting positive & negative nos.
        {
            if(a[i]>0)
            {
                pcount++;
            }
            else
                ncount++;
        }

        //Buffer Array 
        int pos[]=new int[pcount];
        int neg[]=new int[ncount];

        // Inserting into resp. arrays
        for(i=0,j=0,k=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<0 && j<ncount)
            {
                neg[j]=a[i];
                j++;

            }
            if(a[i]>0 && k<pcount)
            {
                pos[k]=a[i];
                k++;

            }               
        }
        System.out.println("Arr "+Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println("Pos "+Arrays.toString(pos));
        System.out.println("Neg "+Arrays.toString(neg));


//Insert into final array
        for(i=0,j=0,k=0;i<(len);i++)
        {


            if(i%2==0 && j<pcount)
            {
                b[i]=pos[j];
                j++;

            }
            if(i%2!=0 && k<ncount)
            {
                b[i]=neg[k];
                k++;
            }   
        }
        //Final no. correction 
        System.out.println("Final "+Arrays.toString(b));

    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting vs what you expect?

Comment: I was getting this [12, -1, 3, -2, 4, -9, 8, -6, 4, 0] and I wanted                         [12, -1, 3, -2, 4, -9, 8, -6, 4, 78]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(pcount >ncount && k>=ncount)
{
  b[i]=pos[j];
  j++;
}
else if(ncount >pcount && j>=pcount)
{
  b[i]=neg[k];
  k++;
}
```

Use the rest "if" statements as "else if"